# JSONArray to JSONObject error from string using Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

Many similar questions/answers out in SO but unfortunately I was unable to find an QA like mine that I could solve the problem with.

I have a function which accepts an array of objects. This array is changed to a string and then is supposed to return an JSONObject. The exact function is:

```
fun schoolsIdsToJson(schoolIds: ArrayList<Schools.schoolIds>): JSONObject {
    val baseType: Type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Schools.schoolIds>>(){}.type
    val gson = GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create()
    val json = gson.toJson(schoolIds, baseType) //, baseType
    var jsonResp: String = json.toString()
    jsonResp = jsonResp.replace("\"[{]", "{")
    jsonResp = jsonResp.replace("[}]\"", "}")

    Log.e("schoolsIdsToJson", jsonResp)
    return JSONObject(jsonResp)
}
```

When I log *jsonResp* the string is [{"_id":626}] which is correct. But when I put the string into the JSONObject, it throws the error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"_id":626}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Now, I would expect this if I didn't change it to a string but when it's a string I'm confused as to why the error happens.

Any pointers of what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks,
^.^

UPDATE

Thx for everyone's help. The cause is that I was mixing things up. Took awhile for me to understand that. Here is the comment that sorted things out for me. Maybe it'll help someone else.

> Again, you're mixing the things up: the variable is a Java string, but the data it holds is a JSON array that cannot be converted to a JSON object like that -- it is just illegal. Either make that method return JSONArray (or whatever appropriate from the org.json package; I haven't worked with it), or extract the first value from the result array (that does not make much sense in that code either)

Comment: Don't `org.json.JSONObject` and `com.google.gson.JsonObject` look suspecting to you? + UPD: Why using `JSONObject` if it's generating an array?

Comment: Also `[{"_id":626}]` is indeed an array and not an object. It is an array with one element (which is an object).

Comment: Also, that thing, with uhm `.replace(...)` looks odd.

Comment: @fluffy I didn't understand what you mean by org.json.JSONObject and com.google.gson.JsonObject. Can you tell more? I commented out the replace but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @MicahMontoya No, we don't mean the type of the `jsonResp` (that does not make much sense here, but is a Java string, the type of the variable), but the type of the JSON value it holds: it **is** an array, a value enclosed with `[` and `]`.

Comment: @Henry Yes, it was an array but I changed it to a string. Even if I try to do JSONObject(jsonResp.toString()), it just tells me that toString is redundant so I'm suspecting it is an string.

Comment: @fluffy Thx for that. Yes, but since it's a string now, isn't it? Isn't doing json.toString() changing it to a string and not an string array?

Comment: @MicahMontoya Again, you're mixing the things up: the variable is a Java string, but the _data_ it _holds_ is a JSON array that cannot be converted to a JSON object like that -- it is just illegal. Either make that method return `JSONArray` (or whatever appropriate from the `org.json` package; I haven't worked with it), or extract the first value from the result array (that does not make much sense in that code either).

Comment: @fluffy That makes sense now. Took awhile for me to understand. Thx for your time.